# Is it possible to capture/save JPEGs from an MJPEG stream? (and also the MJPEG itself)?

Tags: android, video-streaming, extract, mjpeg

I am using [MJPEG-Streamer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mjpg-streamer/) to stream an MJPEG video file over http, [similar to how this guy does it](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/stream-video-from-the-raspberry-pi-camera-to-web-browsers-even-on-ios-and-android). MJPEG-Streamer basically creates a streaming server on the streaming device which hosts the MJPEG video being streamed. This stream can be accessed via `http://<Server-IP-address>:8080/?action=stream`. An example of this is http://sigsiu.homeip.net/?action=stream. Snapshots can be captured with `http://<Server-IP-address>:8080/?action=snapshot`

The thing I'm curious about is the format that the stream is received in: `/?action=stream`. Is this a normal protocol for how multimedia is streamed, or is this something MJPEG-Streamer specific?

Most importantly, would it be possible for me to extract JPEGs / the MJPEG when it is streaming via `/?action=stream`

I'm very new to streaming live videos over the internet, so I have no idea how to tell if MJPEG-Streamer is streaming in some very standard way, in which it would be easy to extract the JPEGs/MJPEG; or if its streaming in some esoteric way that's a little cryptic, where it's difficult to extract the JPEGs/MJPEG.

Thank you!

Some extra info: I plan on receiving/capturing the MJPEG stream on an Android device